# How to hit multiple http request in jmeter after taking a value from csv file

Tags: loops, csv, controller, jmeter

I have a testing plan in which I have to check login of the application
so when I hit the login `API` then another 5 concurrent `API` request initiated in the case of Application

I simulated the same in `JMeter`.

but my system is working like this
 first, it makes login to 10 users and then other `HTTP` requests are initiated , and **I want it to like**

[image]

First, take one value from `CSV` file and hit login API and then hit other 4  and same is repeated for all users.

Comment: Are you looking to run your testplan for 10 iterations? In that case, you don't need 10 users. You need 1 user for 10 loops

Comment: heyy.. thankeww .... :*